# Opencart website getting request from random subdomains (DDoS)

Tags: dns, ddos

We have an Opencart 3.0.3 website which is getting DDoSed, we then migrated it to AWS and noticed the same thing happening, we blocked access from all other countries except US & Canada. For admin we added a `.htaccess` rule to only allow from a single IP and added 7g-firewall rules.
but we are still experiencing the issues

[image]

[image]

The site is getting DDoS'ed from random subdomins

```
http://www.database.indousplaza.com 
http://www.king.indousplaza.com 
http://www.pc49.indousplaza.com
```

For now we have have closed the site.